# Why are the products not shown?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

```
<?php
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax');
    
    function filter_ajax(){

    $category = $_POST['category'];

   
     $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'post_type'=>'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
             if(isset($category)) {
               $args['category__in'] = array($category);
             }
```

The category id is delivered, but it is not clear to me why the products of this selected category are not displayed

```
             $loop = new WP_Query($args);
             if($loop->have_posts()):
             while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
             ?>             
            
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-products">
              <li class="list-group-item select-blue-essence">
                 <div class="row in-list-text">
                    <div class="col-4 text-center font-poppins js-filter">
                        <span class="fw-bold"><?php the_title();?></span><br>
                      <span><?php the_content();?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 price-tag font-poppins fw-bold"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                   <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              </div>
        <?php endwhile; 
            endif; 
           wp_reset_postdata(); 
       die(); 
      
} ?>
```

Comment: 'taxonomy' => 'product' is incorrect.  It should be  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat','post_type'=>'product',

Comment: I changed it, but nothing is still shown @ElvinHaci

Comment: You need to var_dump($args); to see the final arguments. Maybe there is some problem with $_POST["category"]; And one more thing - category_in is wrong as well. That is for category taxonomy. But in your case your taxonomy is product_cat. To use category_in like parameter for product_cat, check TAX QUERY section of this docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: I understand and read Tax Query but I keep the id taken from the selected category, it should show the products through it. Thanks for trying to help me. @ElvinHaci
https://prnt.sc/OwYieSVL3tTr var_dump($args)

Comment: Yes your var_dump output clearly shows that the last problem you need to solve is removing category_in. Check mujuonly's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$category = isset($_POST['category']) :?array(absint($_POST['category'])) : array();
    
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'id', 
            'terms'     => $category
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Try this - Category IDs should be integer

Comment: Or like me, just data-category change from $cat-term_id to  $cat->name and get a product by category name. Thank you very much, I appreciate your work  :D