# Problem with query products in WooCommerce with category argument in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I tried to query products by WP_query and it was all fine. But when i tried query it with category argument nothing happenned. When i trying add new shortcode with category args it doesn't work too. I can't see where the problem is. I don't think that swiper.js could make a error. When i enter empty 'category_name' it shows all products. Others argument work as they should

```
function test_short($attr) {

$content = '';
$content .= "<script src='https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js'></script>";
    
    $sharg = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat' => '',
    ), $attr );

    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'category_name' => 'gry',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );
    
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    $content .= '<div class="swiper slidee">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">';

    if($wc_query->have_posts()) {
        while($wc_query->have_posts()) {
            $content .= '<div class="swiper-slide">';
            $wc_query->the_post();
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'full')[0];
            $content .= '<img class="product_img" src="'.$url.'">';
            $title = get_the_title();
            $content .= "<div class='title'>".$title."</div>";
            $product = wc_get_product( $id );
            $content .= number_format(($product->get_price()),2)." zł";
            $content .= '
            <a href="?add-to-cart='.$id.'" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="'.$id.'" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Dodaj „'.$title.'” do koszyka" rel="nofollow"><div class="koszyk_ikona"></div><div class="koszyk_tekst">Dodaj do koszyka</div></a>
            ';
            $content .= '</div>';
        }   
    }



    
    
    $content .= '
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div';
 $content .= "<script>";
$content .= file_get_contents(get_site_url().'/javascript.js');
$content .= "</script>";

$content .= '<script type="text/javascript"> var swiper = new Swiper(".slidee", {
    slidesPerView: 3.5,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    autoplay: {
     delay: 3000,
    },
    speed: 1700,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  });
  </script>';   
wp_reset_query();
return $content;
}
add_shortcode("test_short","test_short");
```

EDIT!!!!
I discovered that no of my products have category when i check them by get_the_category(). How is possible when i added them to category and at products admin panel they all have some of category

Comment: Product category != category. `category` is the basic default taxonomy WP provides, but WooCommerce product categories are their _own_ taxonomy. So you'll need to add a proper tax_query, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: Thank you for response. I just realised when I query products they don't have any taxonomy or category. I think the problem is in it but i don't know how to resolved it

Comment: They have a _product category_, which _is_ a taxonomy. The name of that taxonomy is `product_cat`.

Comment: Thank you Mate!! It worked. Sorry for missunderstanding you at begin. Have a great day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the products not shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198543/why-are-the-products-not-shown)

Comment: Yes. That answered my question. Products didn't show bc I wrote 'category' instead 'product_cat' in WP Query args

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = array('Clothing', 'Bed');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $category
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($loop->have_posts()):
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($product->get_name());
        echo '</pre>';
    endwhile;
endif;
```